# Probability of a randomly sampled subset being Byzantine

Tags: probability, combinations

I have been working on writing a white paper to describe a consensus algorithm I have been creating. Please note I am a computer scientist, not a mathematician, though I am happy to do lots of reading on any topics people link in. I like to understand the why of a solution, not just the solution.

The problem at hand is, I have *n* validators, where ε percent of them are controlled by an adversary. These *n* validators are shuffled using a random fisher Yates shuffle. They are then split into *k* uniform “shards” or committees. Each committee has an equal number of validators in it.

A committee can be considered Byzantine/corrupt if more than 3/4*c* (where c is the number of validators per committee, aka n/k) members are controlled by the adversary.

Given this information (ε, *n*, *k*, *c*) and assuming a random shuffling of the “list” of the validators can we calculate the probability of a random sample producing a set of committees where one or more committees are “corrupt”?

I know that there can be *n* choose *k* possible combinations, but am stuck on how to take this combined with the percentage of validators who are adversary (ε) and produce a probability.

A more generic expression of the above problem is to imagine there are n coloured pieces of card, a card can be either red or green. ε percent of the cards are red. The cards are shuffled with a truly random & unpredictable shuffling algorithm. Then the top n/k cards are taken from the top of the pile and placed into their own pile, this is done k times. The colour of the card is unknown until all cards have been split into cards (ie the cards are face down)

EYou now have k piles of cards of length c (where c = n/k). Each pile's cards colour is then revealed (ie flipped over) and then tested using the following rule: "if 3/4 or more of the cards in a pile is red, then that pile is RED, otherwise that pile is GREEN)."

What is the probability that at least one of the sampled piles is RED, and the probability of i piles being red (while k - i piles are green).  (given ε, n, k)

Thank you very much, and any help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if my notation or terminology is incorrect or if I can improve the way I have asked my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given

$$
\begin{align}
n & \text{ : the number of validators}, \newline
k & \text{ : the number of committees}, \newline
\varepsilon & \text{ : the percentage of adversarial validators}, \newline
c & \text{ : the number of validators per committee} = \bigg\lfloor \frac n k \bigg\rfloor
\end{align}
$$

Let

$$
C_i : \text{ the set of validators in committe $i$}.
$$

There are $\lfloor \varepsilon n \rfloor$ corrupt validators in total. If $v = \frac {3\lfloor n/k \rfloor} 4$ or more corrupt validators are assigned to a single committee then we have a vulnerable assignment.

For a committee to be vulnerable, the probability is given by

$$
\pi = \overbrace{{\frac {\lfloor \varepsilon n \rfloor} {n}} \times {\frac {\lfloor \varepsilon n \rfloor - 1} {n-1}} \cdots \times {\frac {\lfloor \varepsilon n \rfloor - (v-1)} {n-(v-1)}}}^{v \text{ adversarial validators}} \times \overbrace {1 \times 1 \times \cdots \times 1}^{\lfloor n/k \rfloor -v \text{ times}}
$$

> **Note:** The above calculation is similar to picking $v$ red balls from an urn containing red and white balls while picking $\lfloor n/k \rfloor$ total balls without replacement.

For a committee to be invulnerable, the probability is

$$
p = 1 - \pi
$$

For $k$ committees to be invulnerable, we should use conditional probabilities (because the $j$-th committee being invulnerable depends on the previous $j-1$ committees' vulnerability statuses):

The probability that $C_1$ is invulnerable is

$$p_1 = p = 1 - \pi.$$

The probability that $C_2$ is invulnerable is

$$
\begin{align}
p_2 & = P(C_2 \text{ is invulnerable}|C_1 \text{ is invulnerable}) \\
    & = \frac {P(C_2 \text{ is invulnerable} \land C_1 \text{ is invulnerable})} {P(C_2 \text{ is invulnerable})} \\
    & = \frac {p \times p} {p} \\
    & = p  
\end{align}
$$

The probability that $C_3$ is invulnerable is

$$
\begin{align}
p_2 & = P(C_3 \text{ is invulnerable}| C_2 \text{ is invulnerable}\land C_1 \text{ is invulnerable}) \\
& = \frac {P(C_3 \text{ is invulnerable} \land C_2 \text{ is invulnerable}\land C_1 \text{ is invulnerable}} {P(C_3 \text{ is invulnerable})} \\
& = \frac {p \times p \times p} p \\
& = p^2
\end{align}
$$

Similarly, the probability that $C_j$ is invulnerable is

$$p_j = p^{j-1}$$

The probability that all $C_i$ are invulnerable is

$$
\begin{align}
\prod_{i=1}^k p_i & = p \times p \times (p^2) \times (p^3) \times \cdots \ (p^{k-1}) \\
 & = p \cdot p^(1 + 2 + \cdots + k-1) \\
 & = p \cdot p^{(k-1)k/2} \\
 & = p^{(k-1)k/2 + 1}
\end{align}
$$

The probability that at least one committee is vulnerable is given by

$$
1 - p^{(k-1)k/2 + 1}
$$

Comment: Hi thank you for your answer! It lol am great but there’s just one or two bits I think might be off. 

Specifically the statement “if more than 3(/k)/4 corrupt validators are assigned to a committee the committee  is corrupt”. If (3/4)c (where cis the number of members in a committee  or c = n/k) validators are corrupt the committee is corrupt. I don’t think this expands to your given formula. Sorry this id likly due to my poor formatting of the answer. If this is factored in, how do the other equations change?

Comment: Also assume that “random sample” means that the set of validators is truely randomly shuffled. This is done with a modified version of the fisher-Yates shuffle using a truely random input. Then this set is split into k slices. So by random sample I mean the order of the validators before being split is shuffled randkmly

Comment: Good catch. The equations are correct, the phrasing wasn't. I have edited it to "If $\frac {3\lfloor \varepsilon n/k \rfloor} 4$ or more...."

Comment: Also, the FY shuffle is already being considered when we are picking a random validator to assign to the committee. So, no further modification of calculations necessary.

Comment: doing some test calculations that doesn’t seem accurate. The correct statement is if more than (3/4)x(n/k) corrupt  validators are assigned to a committee it is corrupt. For example with 1000 total validators, 10 shards the number of tolerable corrupt validators a single committee can tolerate is (3/4)x 100 or 75. I’m not sure how epsilon, the percent of validators who are corrupt, affects this value? Even if 90% of validators are corrupt, you would still need 75 corrupt validators in a single committee for it to be corrupt.

Comment: One other thing, I see that you say the probability of a commuter being corrupt is given by epsilon^(3(n/k)/4). Would you be able to give me the name of this proof or theorem this is based on so I could go and do some personal research on it as I like to have a good understanding of the maths I am using.

Comment: @LeahCornelius: There is an error in the calculation $ε^{3⌊εn/k⌋/4}$. I was using a coin-toss model (eg: $r$ flips and probability of $s$ heads). But consecutive choices of a validator for a committee are not independent events. So, we need to do conditional probability calculation there as well. Let me make an edit.

Comment: ah i see. Yep, unfortunately the coin flip model doesn't quite fit. I have edited my question with a generic model that (i believe) accurately describes the problem

Comment: Hi, the changes look great but there is still one point I'm not sure about. v=3⌊εn/k⌋/4 is not the condition for a committee to be corrupt. It is (3/4)(n/k) or 3(n/k)/4, ε does not factor into it as the number of corrupt validators that must be assigned to a committee for it to be corrupt is constant for a given n, k

Comment: I am also confused by what multiplying the sum by 1 (n/k) - v times archives, surely this can just be removed from the equation

Comment: @LeahCornelius: You are right. It should be $v = \frac {3\lfloor n/k \rfloor} 4$. I've made the edit. The $(\lfloor n/k \rfloor - v)\times 1$ is only there for completeness. It shows that once we have made $v$ vulnerable assignments, it doesn't matter what the remaining $\lfloor n/k \rfloor - v$ assignments are for the probability of the committee's vulnerability status.